# autocomplete broken on visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

**Desired behavior** (that worked up till now):

1. I type "MySo" and the intellisense suggests "MySolution"
2. I press ENTER and there it is: "MySolution"
3. I press dot and intellisense suggests "ViewModels" among other options
4. I type "Vie" to highlight ViewModels
5. I press ENTER and there it is: "MySolution.ViewModels"
6. I press dot and intellisense suggests "ContactViewModel" among other options
7. I type "Con" to highlight ContactViewModel
8. I press ENTER and there it is:
   "MySolution.ViewModels.ContactViewModel"

**This is happening** (after nVidia manager restarted my PC):

1. I type "MySo" and ... nothing happens

   2. So I type it all by hand "MySolution"
   3. I press dot and intellisense suggests "ViewModels" among other options
   4. I type "Vie" to highlight ViewModels
   5. I press ENTER and there it is: "MySoViewModels.Vie"

--- Help me guys. Thank you. ---

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted.  I am experiencing the same issue.  Intellisense for razor views appears to be broken in VS 2015 Update 3.  The auto-complete is buggy.  It doesn't complete the namespace or class names when you hit "tab", and then suddenly it will autocomplete with only part of the words and messes up the structure of the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008

Also make sure you have no errors above where you are typing.

I have noticed also sometimes if you close the page an reopen it intellisense works again this was a bug in 2013 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and they are working on a fix for VS 2015 Update 3.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues.md